# Getting SUM of AVERAGE in single step SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, subquery, average

I have dataset which looks like below:

```
cat subcat  amount
a   x1      1
a   x1      1
a   x1      1
a   x2      4
a   x2      4
a   x3      6
a   x4      3
a   x5      7
```

What I want the SQL query to do is to:

1. Take the `AVG` value in each 'subcat'
2. Take the `SUM` at a 'cat' level

The resulting dataset after step 1 should be :

```
cat subcat  amount
a   x1      1
a   x2      4
a   x3      6
a   x4      3
a   x5      7
```

The resulting dataset after step 2 should be :

```
cat amount
a   21
```

Now I know this can be easily achieved using a sub-query or creating a temporary table. But I want this to be done in a single step (Without using a sub-query.)

Comment: Why can't you use a subquery? It seems like a very arbitrary restriction.

Comment: Also, is this SQL Server or MySQL? Please choose one only.

Comment: @DavidG I am using SQL Server and thats how the requirement is!!

Comment: What requirement exactly? The only way to get a `SUM` of an `AVG` is to do exactly that, get the `AVG` and then get the `SUM` of that subquery.

Comment: @DavidG Basically I have this table which has the data at 'subcat' level. Now I have around 10 calculated columns and all at a category level. But since this 'amount' column has repeated values at 'subcat' level, I am forced to do the calculation for this column separately and then join back to original table which I am trying to avoid. Hope the requirement is clear now!

Comment: Not really sure I get the requirement there, but it still doesn't mean a subquery is a bad idea. I suppose you could create an indexed view on the table to average the data. That way there is minimal calculation to do for the `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do a CTE? Consider what you're asking for: you want to know the average values of all the rows of a table group based on  2 columns (this means you **must** read all of the rows in the table), and then you want the sum of all the newly created values of each grouping - this data set does not even exist before you begin querying.

Answer (score 0):

The following is technically a sub-query, but only one aggregation would be required IF amounts are truly repeated at the subcat level

```
Declare @Table table (cat varchar(10), subcat varchar(10),  amount decimal(10,2))
Insert into @Table values
('a','x1',  1),
('a','x1',  1),
('a','x1',  1),
('a','x2',  4),
('a','x2',  4),
('a','x3',  6),
('a','x4',  3),
('a','x5',  7)

Select cat,SoA=sum(a.amount) from (Select Distinct * from @Table) A group by cat
```

Returns

```
cat SoA
a   21.00
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sub query:

```
SELECT  cat,
        SUM(amount) as amount
FROM (
    SELECT  cat, 
            subcat, 
            AVG(amount) as amount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY cat, subcat
    ) as p
GROUP BY cat
```

or CTE:

```
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT  cat, 
            subcat, 
            AVG(amount) as amount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY cat, subcat
)

SELECT  cat,
        SUM(amount) as amount
FROM cte
GROUP BY cat
```

Output:

```
cat amount
a   21
```